# IIS You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource Access denied

Tags: iis

While trying to fix some troubles getting to a local webpage on our network in IIS manager i managed to make it completely unavailable.

I thought i had only been messing with Authentication settings in feature view but even after changing everything back i cant seem to view the webpage even on the localhost. 
I get 
Access denied.
you do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Like i said i changed everything i did back.
Reset IIS
Made sure App pool was pointing at correct physical location
Tried to change Anonymous user to Application pool identity
Change anonymous user to a specific user
I dont see anything in the logs but not 100% sure what im looking for..

Thanks!

Comment: check the apppool user has access. what's your apppool called?

Comment: just using defaultAppPool. which has read/Read $execute and list folder contents permissions on the wwwroot directory

Comment: "i changed everything i did back". What did you do and how are you sure you changed everything back? IIS has [backup config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-backup-restore-iis7-configuration). what logs did you look at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hosting ASP.NET in IIS7 gives Access is denied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418669/hosting-asp-net-in-iis7-gives-access-is-denied)

Comment: Just the items in Authentication Feature I was changing some to enabled but i disabled them again afterwards. Does IIS backup single sites and where is the backup config located? I was looking at logs in  C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles and i have tried to use the things on that post with no luck.. Cant seem to find exact error just says Access Denied with no additional detail.