# How to set permission of a website based on ACL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, acl

I want to let my web site be accessible by people in a specific ACL.
I have added my ACL to the Website folder in the server and given it full access.Currently the folder has access given to SYSTEM, ADMIN and the ACL. However, when I try to access the website, I get :

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Now , I add \IIS_IUSRS. Then I can access the website , but so can someone outside of the ACL.The identity of the applicationpool for my website is set to **NetworkService**

How should I address this issue?I need this website to be accessed only by the members of the ACL.

Thanks and help in advance.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13767439/177416

Comment: Look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418669/hosting-asp-net-in-iis7-gives-access-is-denied